# Как запустить несколько потоков в python 3.9

Tags: python, threading

Этот участок кода должен вызывать класс MainThread(threading.Thread) количество раз которое ровно количеству working_ports(в моем случае 3), а главное одновременно. Но они вызываются по очереди, то есть второй поток запускаеться только после того как я заканчиваю действия в первом. Буду рад если кто то объяснит почему так происходит. Код:

````
        rooms_db_connection = sql.connect('E:\\MAN\\rooms.db')
        rooms_cursor = rooms_db_connection.cursor()

        available_ports, working_ports = listing_ports()
        all_theads = {}
        all_ports = 0
        for port in working_ports:
            thread_name = ("thread" + str(all_ports))
            rooms_cursor.execute(F"SELECT room_name FROM rooms WHERE port={port}")
            room_name = rooms_cursor.fetchall()
            all_theads[thread_name] = MainThread(f"{room_name}", port)
            all_theads[thread_name].start()
            all_ports += 1

        rooms_db_connection.commit()
        rooms_cursor.close()```
````

Comment: Что такое `MainThread`? Может быть, именно его реализация `__init__` и тормозит?

Comment: @andreymal делаю ставку, что именно в этом дело. Либо в **star**t.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Ваша ставка сыграла! Не замечал что в __init__ был вписан self.run(). Спасибо.